# c++ statement has no effect

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm having problems with some homework and I can't find the answer.

I have to do a simple program that solves a math problem, but it does not comp

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a, b, FirstA;
    int result = 0;
    FirstA = a;

    // The sum of the cubes between a and b: (a^3 + (a + 1)^3 + .. + (b + 1)^3 + b^3)
    while (cin >> a >> b) {
        for (a; a <= b; a++) {
            result = result + pow(a,3);
        }
        cout << "suma dels cubs entre " << FirstA << " i " << b << ": " << result << endl;
    }

}
```

The error it gives is this:

```
program.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
program.cc:23:15: error: statement has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     for (a; a <= b; a++) {
```

All warnings being treated as errors.

What should I do?

Comment: don't use `std::istream::operator>>`. Use `std::getline()` instead for getting one line of user input, and then parse the line after the fact.

Comment: @Coeus While it is common practice, `return 0` is implicit in `main` if control reaches the closing brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unused value in `for (a; a <= b; a++)` because the `a;` makes no sense.

Use a for-loop without initialization: `for (; a <= b; a++)`.

Comment: I tried doing this but the result stacks up every time I type a new input, but I understand the error now.

Comment: @jonathan9879 I think you should set result as a zero in the each while-loop iteration.

Comment: That fixed the issue, but now value a is always 0

Comment: I just found out why: The FirstA statement has to be in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not resembling the formula in the comment above it and the `for` loop is not defined properly: `for (a; a <= b; a++)`.
A possible solution is to replace:

```
for (a; a <= b; a++) {
//---^
    result = result + pow(a,3);
}
```

with:

```
cin >> a >> b;

int n = 10; // number of iterations
int i = 0;    
int j = n;    

do{
    ++i;
    --j;
    result += pow(a + i, 3) + pow(b + j, 3);
}while(i <= n);
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the same problem as the other solution: the result stacks up with each new input. In addition, it always gives a as 0.